# Using the spread function correctly

Tags: r, tidyr

My data "IDrel" has three variables, "ID", "category" and "value", it looks something like this:

```
    ID  category value
1       AU: Duflo, Esther
2   2   AF: MIT
3   3   SO: American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2(2), April 2010, pp.
4   4   IS: 1945-7782
5   5   AV: http://www.aeaweb.org/aej-applied/
6   6   DT: Journal Article
7   7   PY: 2010
8   8   AN: 1094392
9   9   TI: Prize Structure and Information in Tournaments: Experimental Evidence
10  10  AU: Freeman, Richard B.; Gelber, Alexander M.
11  11  AF: NBER; NBER
12  12  SO: American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2
```

There are 9 unique values of "category", and I want to make each of them into their own variable, with values represented by the "value"-variable. In theory, this should increase the number of variables to 11 and reduce the number of observations by something like 9/10.

The desired output looks something like this:

```
ID    AU:            SO.                           IS:          [more variables]

    1     Duflo, Esther   American Economic Journal    1945-7782    [more values]
    2     Freeman, Richard American Economic Journal:  [...]
```

I try to achieve this via the spread-function:

```
IDspread<-spread(IDrel, category, value)
```

I actually do get 11 variables, but I get the same number of observations. The results seem nonsensical to me, these are the first 10 observations:

```
IS:  PY:
1      <NA> <NA>
2      <NA> <NA>
3      <NA> <NA>
4 1945-7782 <NA>
```

Am I using this function correctly? Is there an alternative?

I realize the ID variable doesn't reflect which category/value belongs with which observation, but I need to reorder the data in order to "get" the correct index for each observation ^^

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the use of `ID` variable.  It is having unique values.  So, if we keep that variable while doing `spread`, the number of rows in the `spread` output would be equal to the number of unique elements in 'ID' and combinations that doesn't exist would be `NA`.  Remove the 'ID', create a sequence column grouped by 'category' (to take care of duplicates) and then `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
IDrel %>%        
   group_by(category) %>% 
   mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% # update the ID column
   spread(category, value)
# A tibble: 2 x 10
#    ID `AF:`    `AN:`  `AU:`                `AV:`             `DT:`     `IS:`  `PY:` `SO:`                          `TI:`                         
#  <int> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>                <chr>             <chr>     <chr>  <chr> <chr>                          <chr>                         
#1     1 MIT      10943… Duflo, Esther        http://www.aeawe… Journal … 1945-… 2010  American Economic Journal: Ap… Prize Structure and Informati…
#2     2 NBER; N… <NA>   Freeman, Richard B.… <NA>              <NA>      <NA>   <NA>  American Economic Journal: Ap… <NA>
```

#### data

```
IDrel <- structure(list(ID = 1:12, category = c("AU:", "AF:", "SO:", "IS:", 
"AV:", "DT:", "PY:", "AN:", "TI:", "AU:", "AF:", "SO:"), value = c("Duflo, Esther", 
"MIT", "American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2(2), April 2010, pp.", 
"1945-7782", "http://www.aeaweb.org/aej-applied/", "Journal Article", 
"2010", "1094392", "Prize Structure and Information in Tournaments: Experimental Evidence", 
"Freeman, Richard B.; Gelber, Alexander M.", "NBER; NBER", "American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Comment: There is an uneven number of rows in each category. There are for instance less instances of AU: (with corresponding "valiue) since many articles are written anonymously. 

Will your solution take this into account (so that some values for AU: is left blank) or will the order be affected when we group the observations by category?

Comment: @Magnus. yes, that is the reason I did a group by `row_number()`.  Let's say if you have 5, 6, 7, rows in different catogories.  Then, in the final `spread`, it would have the max number of row, ie 7, and all the combinations that are not. exist will be `NA`

Comment: Your code seems to work, I'm just trying to wrap my head around it. I have only ever seen the group_by verb being used with aggregate functions (so basically like in SQL queries) so I have no idea how or why it can interact with the row_number()-function.

I will mark this as the answer, but could you please explain how this works under the hood (else point me to a suitable resource!)

Comment: @Magnus It is just to create an identifier for row.  Suppose you have an element repeeated 'n' times, `spread` will not know which row that repeated element would go unless there is an identifier ssaying that it is 1, 2, 3, ... N and `row_number()` is ddoing that

Comment: I understand that's what it's doing (I piped the code into a another object and checked the index numbers), I'm just not sure "how" its done. In my mind, the group_by-verb should basically clump all of the valuesof each category together. Seen from that perspective the row number should either be the same for each category or  strech from 1 to the number values of the group?

Comment: @Magnus For that, you may need to check the source code of `spread`

Comment: Hrrrm, I notice now that all the Article numbets without an author are clumped near the end. This is what might be expected if row numbers were given internally in each group since that would mean the AN:-group would have the largest amount of rows. Since several of the Article numbers at the end appear to  have authors listed in the source file I have to conclude that this method has altered the order somehow, I guess I'll have to forego the spread-function entirely and build a for-loop or something ^^

Comment: @Magnus If there is no article number, that is `blank`, then it would be clumped as a ssingle group.  You can do one more grouping with `rleid(Article numbers)` so that adjacent elementss are grouped together, then do the `row_number()`

Answer (score 1):

This not a direct answer to the question on  `spread()` but the data looks pretty damn similar to `DCF` format.

`DCF` is a simple format for storing databases in plain text files and can be read directly from file using base R's `read.dcf()` function.

So, if the data would be stored in file `IDrel.dcf`

> ```
> AU: Duflo, Esther
> AF: MIT
> SO: American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2(2), April 2010, pp.
> IS: 1945-7782
> AV: http://www.aeaweb.org/aej-applied/
> DT: Journal Article
> PY: 2010
> AN: 1094392
> TI: Prize Structure and Information in Tournaments: Experimental Evidence
>
> AU: Freeman, Richard B.; Gelber, Alexander M.
> AF: NBER; NBER
> SO: American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2
> ```

the command

```
read.dcf("IDrel.dcf", all = TRUE)
```

would return the data.frame

> ```
>                                          AU         AF                                                                  SO        IS
> 1                             Duflo, Esther        MIT American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2(2), April 2010, pp. 1945-7782
> 2 Freeman, Richard B.; Gelber, Alexander M. NBER; NBER                     American Economic Journal: Applied Economics, 2      <NA>
>                                   AV              DT   PY      AN                                                                    TI
> 1 http://www.aeaweb.org/aej-applied/ Journal Article 2010 1094392 Prize Structure and Information in Tournaments: Experimental Evidence
> 2                               <NA>            <NA> <NA>    <NA>
> ```

Note that the empty line indicates the beginning of a new record.

The `DCF` rules as implemented in R are explained in the help file `?read.dcf`.